# How to use addClass method in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, addclass

I have an angularjs directive restricted to class. How can I add this by using addClass method in angularjs

**directive**

```
app.directive('number', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function () {         

    }
};
```

});

**code**

```
 <div id="test"></div>
```

I know it is possible by using jQuery like the following.

```
$( "#test" ).addClass( "number" );
```

Please help me in doing it by using angularjs

Comment: you can do this same way you do in jquery. `element.addClass('number')`. all you got to do is find the element. you can use `find()` method. but it is limited to lookups by tag name.

Comment: here element means my div id ?

Comment: i already told you can only find element with element name. not id. here element is your div.

Comment: You cannot add directive class dynamically onto the html. html has to be compiled before any directive can work on it. Since you want to  add it dynamically it would not work? Why do you want to do like this. Please explain your scenario.

Comment: I have to give this class to one of the value which comes through a ng-repeat

Comment: I think your scenario shouldn't work, even with ng-repeat. Because ng-repeat instantiates a template at once and afterwards reuse it.
Add your class directive simply to html, not dynamically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to use .addClass() angular provide ng-class directive to add class conditionally.

```
ng-class="{number:[condition]}"
```

it will add class number whenever your condition return true

yes but your directive will not be used by this I misunderstood your question previously.

Answer (score 4):

You should add `ng-class="yourClass"` to element on view and add in your controller

`$scope.yourClass = "your-new-class"`, not in directive

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
 link: function (lEmel) {         
      lElem.addClass("Foo");
    }
```