# Ionic Enlarge Font Size

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I've seen it on several apps, but can't seem to figure it out.  I simply want to place a icon for font (with + and -) where the user clicks it, it will enlarge the font size or decrease it.

Comment: Create a small text and large text class in css and then just add or remove it with ng-click --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488293/how-to-use-addclass-method-in-angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/j06rBhJd914wmgFsPV5d?p=preview).

**controllers.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.size = 14;
    $scope.fontSize = "font-size-" + $scope.size;

    $scope.increase = function(){
        //Higher limit
        if($scope.size < 18){
            $scope.size++;
            $scope.fontSize = "font-size-" + $scope.size;
        }
    };

    $scope.decrease = function(){
        //Lower limit
        if($scope.size > 14){
            $scope.size--;
            $scope.fontSize = "font-size-" + $scope.size;
        }
    };
});
```

**tab-dash.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
  <ion-content class="padding" ng-class="fontSize">
    <button class="button" ng-click="increase()"><i class="ion-plus-round"></i></button>
    <button class="button" ng-click="decrease()"><i class="ion-minus-round"></i></button>
    <div class="list card">
      <div class="item item-divider">Recent Updates</div>
      <div class="item item-body">
        <div>
          There is a fire in <b>sector 3</b>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list card">
      <div class="item item-divider">Health</div>
      <div class="item item-body">
        <div>
          You ate an apple today!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list card">
      <div class="item item-divider">Upcoming</div>
      <div class="item item-body">
        <div>
          You have <b>29</b> meetings on your calendar tomorrow.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**style.css**

```
.font-size-14 *{
    font-size: 14px;
}

.font-size-15 *{
    font-size: 15px;
}

.font-size-16 *{
    font-size: 16px;
}

.font-size-17 *{
    font-size: 17px;
}

.font-size-18 *{
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

I added the lower and higher limits so an user can't go over these two `font-size`s.